# IDENT_CURRENT on inserted table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm fairly new to SQL Server, and I'm trying to create a trigger that will capture the identity column of a table when an update statement is executed. What I have now is:

```
SET @myVar = IDENT_CURRENT('inserted');
```

But this always returns `NULL` (which, from [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx), means there is an error or I don't have permissions).

Has anyone come across a similar problem with the inserted table? Any tips for debugging. I'm not sure what kind of permissions issue this would be. I've also tried using `@@IDENTITY` and `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, but they return the identity of a table use after I set `@myVar` (which I find to be a little odd).

Answer (score 1):

If it is the trigger for INSERT or UPDATE, then will be created temporary table called "INSERTED". Check this column INSERTED.your_identity_column.

Comment: Right, I'm already using the inserted table as my post says, but I'm trying to make this generic, so I'd like to dynamically get the identity column instead of hard-coding it.

Comment: then SET @myVar = IDENT_CURRENT('your_real_table');

Comment: @redgem - Don't worry abort making it generic, use the appropriate column.  People who write triggers that can only handle a single row, e.g. by using a variable to hold _the_ row id, also eat kittens.  Do not use `IDENT_CURRENT` unless you need random numbers.  It works without regard for session or scope so the value it returns may not be "yours".  Use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` in code that performs `INSERT`s and `inserted`/`deleted` in triggers.